# Excel: Reflecting changes of some columns on one other when a record inserted or removed in first columns set

Tags: excel

Assume I have two columns A, B

Source Data:

[image]

Then I want to have a column in another part of my same excel sheet or another excel sheet (same document) which makes a decision to show values on column A according to column B (Using if function : show A if B = 1 or else show 0).

My goal is this:

1) When somebody inserts a record in source data (A, B) or removes a record it reflects to second part automatically (new record insert or remove in results part)

2) I don't want to put results in the same rows. In this example source data started from row 3 but I like to put result from first row or row number 100 onward

Thank you in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve your goal and how we can contribute to it?

Comment: @ManishChristian I tried write my result part just like this  If(B$3:B$10 = 1, A$3:A$10, 0)  which triggers result part when I insert or remove a record to/from source part. But I need to put result part in the same range of rows (3 to 10). I think of offset function to tackle second problem but it is so tricky

Comment: Also let's say you need your result on other sheet, will your source data always start from Row 3? Will you have data in any other column other than A and B?

Comment: @ManishChristian I should've said I have to rather than I need to

Comment: @ManishChristian No this is just an example, I want result in a different row range of source data. Also different columns

Comment: @ManishChristian In the case of my example I want result get started from row 1 or row 100 or whatever except row 3

Comment: Goal that you are trying to achieve, I pretty sure you have to use macro for that. You will need to use Worksheet_Change event and write your code. And there tons of example available on SO on that topic.

Comment: @ManishChristian What if I don't want to change sheet?

Comment: I am not asking to change the sheet. I am talking about [**`Worksheet_Change`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event which you can use in your VBA code.

Comment: If your data is on Sheet1 then on Sheet2, in any cell you like, put `If(Sheet1!B3=1, Sheete1!A3, 0)` and copy this formula up and down.   There is no need to use a range in the IF statement.